# webdav javascript library

Tags: javascript, webdav

what is the best javascript webdav library ?

I found [davclient.js](http://debris.demon.nl/projects/davclient.js/), but it's not maintained anymore I guess (2007)

I also found an [AJAX Client](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/home), but it costs 550$ ...

Answer (score 2):

There won't appear to be much truly recent work because the protocol is stable and mature. In the history of the protocol, 2007 *is* fairly recent. :-)  FWIW, both your links look like reasonable candidates.

The client libraries included in frameworks and tools are well defined. For example, jQuery includes a webdav module to support RESTful methods. Likewise, you find support for webDAV in Wordpress, Mediawiki, Drupal, as well as python, ruby, and many other projects.

Comment: thanks for your infos. Do you know a Extjs Webdav Library maybe ?

Comment: DavClient.js seems to be broken.